# Eclipse SWT StyledText set caret at specified position forcefully

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, rcp

I have an editor implementation which uses SWT StyledText as an editor area.
When Save Operation is invoked using CTRL+S (not on the toollbar, still focus is present on StyledText) caret is lost. Due to this next keyboard inputs are not received by StyledText.
We need to manually click desired positoin to activate the caret and start typing in the text box.
I did some anyalysis on selection and focus before and after save.

```
   `Control beforeFocusControl = Display.getCurrent().getFocusControl();
    IWorkbenchPart beforeActivePart = getActivePart();
    if (beforeFocusControl instanceof StyledText) {
        StyledText sText = (StyledText) beforeFocusControl;
        Cursor oldCursor = sText.getCursor();
    }

    // save the editor
    EditorWindowManager.getInstance().saveEditors(SnippetEditor);

    Control afterFocusControl = Display.getCurrent().getFocusControl();
    IWorkbenchPart afterActivePart = getActivePart();
    // before and after there is no change in selection
    // beforeFocusControl == afterFocusControl
    // beforeActivePart == afterActivePart
    if (afterFocusControl instanceof StyledText) {
        StyledText sText = (StyledText) afterFocusControl;
        //as old focus control was same i tried force setting the cursor and focus
        sText.setCursor(sText.getCursor());
        sText.forceFocus();
    }`
```

There is no change in focus or workbench selection. So i tried to set the caret again and force focus the StyledText but this did not get back the caret to last edited location.

Is there any convenient api in jface to do this ? I know the caret position where it was last present before it was lost.

Comment: I don't get this in an editor I have using StyledText so it is probably something in your code - EditorWindowManager perhaps.

Comment: @greg-449 I agree. I am also not facing this issue in Editor. It's a custom editor present in ViewPart. I also agree that EditorWindowManager may be removing cursor. But as i have position known already, if we can get a jface api to do it forcefully i will just call it after save.

Comment: If the part is still the active part and the focus control is still the styledtext the problem is not the control focus. It is not at all clear what the issue is from this.

Comment: As an aside nothing you show here is JFace. StyledText is SWT. JFace classes are in the org.eclipse.jface package (TextViewer for example).

Comment: @greg-449 sorry about wrong tittle. i have corrected it. The issue is editing cursor is lost  after save. Subsequent keyboard strokes are not received by StyledText. I want programatically make sure StylesText still continue to receive key board strokes. I mean put the cursor back to StyledText.

Comment: @greg-449 also it's the caret missing to accept the text input. So i need to put back the caret to blink and start accepting key board strokes.